# Classic ASP - Regex - pattern is not replacing with string empty

Tags: regex, asp-classic

Am trying to replace content with empty using this regular expression.

```
objRegExp.Pattern = "<(?>/?)(?!(p|strong)(>|\s))[^<]+?>"
sHtml = objRegExp.Replace(sHtml, "")
```

If I test this `<(?>/?)(?!(p|strong)(>|\s))[^<]+?>` regex on [gskinner](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/), it is working fine. But when I place this on **`Classic ASP`** page, it is not working.

When I debug error is shown as

> Syntax error in regular expression

**INPUT:**

```
<h2>Regex testing</h2><br/><p>P Test</p><div>Div Test</div><strong>Strong Test</strong>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
Regex testing<p>P Test</p>Div Test<strong>Strong Test</strong>
```

Please suggest, What's gone wrong here?

Comment: What is the output you actually get?

Comment: @ntziolis: I missed to update the error message "Syntax error in regular expression"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBScript does not support atomic groups (the `(?>/?)` construct at the start).

See [here the feature overview on regular-expression.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html). VBScript is using the ECMA flavour.

Remove the atomic group and replace the check for the leading slash

```
objRegExp.Pattern = "<(?!/?(p|strong))[^<]+?>"
```

This seems to do the job. See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?306dj)

**Update**

OK, I removed too much if you put back `(>|\s)` its working

```
<(?!/?(p|strong)(>|\s))[^<]+?>
```

[Regexr](http://regexr.com?306ee)

Comment: Thanks for answering. The provided regex is removing the closing tags. Your output is `Regex testing<p>P TestDiv Test<strong>Strong Test` and my expected output should be `Regex testing<p>P Test</p>Div Test<strong>Strong Test</strong>`

Comment: @SivaCharan I updated my answer and changed the suggested regex

Comment: stema, still missing few tags. Here is the sample input with your regex - [Regexr](http://regexr.com?306e5) and with the same input my old regex - [Regexr](http://regexr.com?306e8). Problem is with the provided regex, few tags are not replaced. Output should be same as I mentioned in the both regexr URLs. Please suggest.